# Can somebody give me an easy example and explanation of a memory leak in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

Without using the word "reference"?  Easy example and easy explanation please.

I am aware that most modern computers, tablets and phones are fast and do not use IE therefore it is not much of a concern any more but I just want to learn.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: A lot of people use IE. It shouldn't be overlooked.

Comment: So what did Google say? How about http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-jsmemory/index.html?utm_source=tuicool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an *Explain like I'm 5* answer to a memory leak.

- Program: Hey! Give me more memory, I need to save something!
- Operating system: Here! Here you go!
- Program: Hey! Give me more memory, I need to save something!
- Operating system: Here! Here you go!
- Program: Hey! Give me more memory, I need to save something!
- Operating system: Here! Here you go!
- Program: Hey! Give me more memory, I need to save something!
- Operating system: Here! Here you go!
- Program: Hey! Give me more memory, I need to save something!
- Operating system: None left! Sorry
- ***CRASH***

You have to let go of memory you no longer need.

In JavaScript, *MOST* of the time, the system is smart enough to let go of things when they are no longer needed, but you can accidentally hang onto things..

```
   /// Now, this code won't actually run all the way through
   /// because the browser will time out, but lets pretend

   var saveItAll = []; // an array to save everything in.
   var s = "*";        // A string that will keep getting bigger

   while (true) {
     saveItAll.push(s); // Save the string. Use memory.
     s += s; // make the string bigger.
   }
```

After a while, you'll have used all the memory (assuming the program was allowed to run) and the program will crash.

Under older versions of IE it was easy to use up memory by accident because the DOM and JavaScript had different things that kept track of memory, so you could create a `circular reference` between the DOM and your script and thus -- memory would never be released.

The details of that can be Googled... I won't even try to go into them now.